# fill method in CasperJS

Tags: forms, phantomjs, casperjs

I would like to fill a form and submit it.

check a part of my script :

```js
casper.then(function(){
    if(this.exists('#msisdn')){
        this.echo('ok found');
        **this.test.assertExists('form[id="internetPlus"]', 'form is found');
        this.fill('form[id="internetPlus"]', {
            'numero': 'xxxxxxxx'  
        },true);**
        this.click('#button');
```

And I got this error :

```
**PASS form is found**
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector:   
'form[id="internetPlus"]'
**[error] [remote] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating   
'field.getAttribute')
FAIL CasperError: Unable to fill form
#    type: uncaughtError
#    error: "CasperError: Unable to fill form"
CasperError: Unable to fill form                                               
  /home/soufyan/workspace/casperjs:524 in fill
  /home/soufyan/workspace/casperjs/kkostoreHomeTest.js:45
  /home/soufyan/workspace/casperjs:909 in runStep
  /home/soufyan/workspace/casperjs:252 in checkStep**
```

I don't understand why i'm unable to fill form because the assert result is OK.

Comment: Just added proper exception throwing when this kind of error happens https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/commit/78683e2cbf78c9993eadce82f3ed4c10962497c1

Answer (score 0):

The form probably does not contain any inputs or fields with the name 'numero'. Make sure there is an input with that name.

I tried to reproduce your problem by simply adding a junk variable to the object literal that is passed to fill method. I got the exact same error.